# Entropy of a sample distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy

I am simulating a time-dependent diffusion process: each of N variables begins with an identical value ($x_o$), as time progresses, random perturbations are applied (diffusion), and the distribution evolves towards uniformity over a bounded interval $[0, 2\pi)$. Once the uniform distribution has been reached, an observer does not have the ability to determine what the initial state of the system was, this is the maximum entropy case. The goal is to decide when the system has "randomized" ie: reached the maximum entropy state.

The entropy of a histogram representing the probability distribution of a discrete, finite sample is given by $S = -\sum_{i = 1}^{n} p(x_i) \log p(x_i)$ where $n$ is the number of discrete bins representing the possible values of $x$ and $p(x_i) = \frac{k_i}{N}$ where $k_i$ is the population of bin $x_i$.

For an ideal discrete uniform distribution (a histogram of values each with equal probability) $S_{max} = \log n$ where $n$ is the number of discrete bins. However, due to sample variance, this value is never actually reached for a finite random sample.

My question is this:

Is there an expression for the expected maximum entropy $S_{max}$ of a finite, discrete sample from a uniform, continuous, bounded distribution?

Clearly, such an expression should depend on the number of bins $n$ used to discretize the sample population, and the number of samples $N$. Through numerical simulations I have determined a scaling law that estimates the expectation value with the following expression:

$S_{max}(n, N) \approx \log n \big[1 -\frac{n}{N}[An^{-\beta} + c]\big]$

this numerical estimate assumes $N > n$ (the number of samples is greater than the number of bins).

I had to empirically determine the coefficients $A, \beta, c $ by plotting $S_{max} vs. n$ and fitting the resulting curve to the above model. I expect there is a known expression for this function because it seems very fundamental, but have been unable to find it in the literature. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by the "maximum entropy" if a sample?  (2) An object is "discreet" when it is shipped in a plain brown wrapper.

Comment: haha, thanks. yes, these variables don't want anyone to know about their clandestine activities.

Comment: In my case I am looking at a distribution that starts out as a delta function and slowly becomes uniform during a diffusion process, the entropy therefore increases with time. Entropy for a discrete probability distribution $S = -\sum_{x=1}^{n}p(x)\ln p(x)$ is maximum when this distribution is uniform $S_{max} = \ln n$ but there will always be some variance in a finite sample so in reality the expectation value $\langle S_{max} \rangle < \ln n$

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do, because unless your data contain repeat values, $p(x)=1/n$ *always* and the entropy is constantly $n\log(n)$.  This signals a need to describe your statistical assumptions, the nature of your data, and how you might be processing them in order to estimate the $p(x)$.

Comment: Ok, your question shows me that I need to describe this situation in simpler terms. There are a number of variables, N of them to be precise, each with a different, random value selected from a uniform distribution. They are grouped into $n$ bins, the fraction of N that ends up in each bin  is the associated probability, $p(x) = N(x) / n$. So yes, of course there are repeat values, otherwise a histogram makes no sense.

Comment: In this case I am simulating a time-dependent process: each of our $N$ variables begins with an identical value, thus they are all in the same bin, $p(x_i) = 1$, and entropy = 0. As time progresses, random perturbations are applied (diffusion), and the distribution evolves towards uniformity. Once the uniform distribution has been reached, an observer does not have the ability to determine what the initial state of the system was, this is the maximum entropy case.

Comment: wait... regarding your statement, I think it should say: "entropy is constantly $\log(n)$" ( not $n \log(n)$ ), this is the maximum entropy case, a perfectly uniform distribution. For a finite sample this will only happen if you have way way too many bins, it's something of an artifact, typically you want $N/n >> 1$

Comment: You're right:$ -\sum (1/n)\log(1/n) = \log(n)$.  But it's still a constant.  The details given in your comments are crucial for understanding the question, so please elaborate on them by editing the post itself.

Comment: Ok, I made some changes, let me know if you think the question is more clear now.